# Puppet Enterprise and parser=future error. Uninitialized constant Puppet::Pops

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

When trying to set parser=future on PE I get this error

```
 Could not autoload puppet/indirector/node/console: uninitialized constant Puppet::Pops
```

This works using open source puppet 3.6 but not with PE. I'm not sure what is going on here. I'm only attempting to use `each()` in my manifests. I noticed [this issue](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/ENTERPRISE-154) on PE Jira board that seems to be exactly what I am facing but there is no activity since April.

Comment: Hmm, yeah - since it's an endpoint touching the console, it makes sense that this would only be happening on Enterprise - unfortunately, they're probably not too interested in reports of this kind of compatibility problem yet, since the future parser is still experimental.

Comment: (and that ticket is marked as being blocked by ticket `PE-3666`, which I don't have access to see - might be more info there)

Comment: Ticket could use some votes ;-)